# Converting to Universal Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have the following code and I'm not sure how to convert it to the new Universal Analytics for tracking these custom variables:

```
if (_gaq){
    var track = false;
    if(state_list != '0') {
        _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1,         'Selected States',   state_list, 3]);
        track = true;
    }
    if(month_list != '0') {
        _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2,         'Selected Months',   month_list, 3]);
        track = true;
    }
    if(zip_code != '0') {
        _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 3,         'Zip code',          zip_code, 3]);
        track = true;
    }
    if(track) {
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent',  'Schedule', 'search',            undefined, 0, true])
    }
}
```

I'm using this to track page views on another site that has a Universal tracking code:

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

But I'm not sure how to record the custom variables. Essentially I just want to track the values searched for. I understand that custom variables are not available in Universal, you use custom dimensions instead but I can't figure out how to do what we are doing with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In universal analytics its called [custom dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) or [event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

It really depends on what you are doing with that code.  Do you want to track that they clicked on it I wonder if it would be best to track it as an event that will allow you to store the value of the drop down they selected.    The following will log it as a dimension but you will need to set up dimension1 in the admin section.

```
if (_gaq){
var track = false;
if(state_list != '0') {

   ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Selected States');
    track = true;
}
if(month_list != '0') {
   ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Selected Months');

    track = true;
}
if(zip_code != '0') {
   ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Zip code');
    track = true;
}
if(track) {
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent',  'Schedule', 'search',            undefined, 0, true])
}
```

}